# how to open Google Chrome User Manager Directly

Tags: google-chrome

is there any way to open google chrome user manager directly with command line ?

something like: "chrome.exe -user-manager"

i want to choose my profile without open a new window and then switch user.

Chrome User Manager Windows:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8ivZ.jpg

Answer (score 2):

I modified the start menu entry from `"C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Google Chrome"` adding this argument `--profile-directory="Guest Profile"`, now when I open Chrome from the start menu, it launches the user manager directly. Note: This is Windows 10, Chrome version 52.

Comment: This also works on Linux with Chromium (i.e., `chromium --profile-directory="Guest Profile"`), so your argument probably works on all desktop variants of Chrome. Your answer is the only place I could find this information. Thanks!

Comment: This is very, very useful, especially when having a lot of Chrome users, and the drop down list box with users from the top right corner of Chrome still doesn't scroll! Tested on Windows 10 with Chrome 66. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It seems it is not possible but you can launch Chrome using a specific profile:

chrome.exe --profile-directory=Default

Be aware that this switch expects the internal names of the profiles

EDIT: You can see the internal names of the profiles by going to chrome://version/ and checking Profile Path or going to the following folder:

C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data

Comment: what is internal names of the profiles ? for my question in the picture i have two user: User 1 and User 2
so is this correct? chrome.exe --profile-directory=User 1